# how to take data from another js file

Tags: javascript

So, i am new in this JavaScript. my teacher gave me this code(file) its name `location.js` the code is

location.js :

```
export const regencies = [
    {
        "id": "1101",
        "province_id": "11",
        "name": "KABUPATEN SIMEULUE",
        "alt_name": "KABUPATEN SIMEULUE",
        "latitude": 2.61667,
        "longitude": 96.08333
    },
    {
        "id": "1102",
        "province_id": "11",
        "name": "KABUPATEN ACEH SINGKIL",
        "alt_name": "KABUPATEN ACEH SINGKIL",
        "latitude": 2.41667,
        "longitude": 97.91667
    },
    {
        "id": "1103",
        "province_id": "11",
        "name": "KABUPATEN ACEH SELATAN",
        "alt_name": "KABUPATEN ACEH SELATAN",
        "latitude": 3.16667,
        "longitude": 97.41667
    },
export const provinces = [
    {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "ACEH",
        "alt_name": "ACEH",
        "latitude": 4.36855,
        "longitude": 97.0253
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "SUMATERA UTARA",
        "alt_name": "SUMATERA UTARA",
        "latitude": 2.19235,
        "longitude": 99.38122
    },
```

and i want to show the data from my `index.js`

and my teacher gave me this

```
const location = require('./location');
console.log(regencies);
```

when he try its worked, but when i tried its show

```
unexpected token export
```

i've try looking for the answer, but none of them get the asnwer

so, thank you in advance

Comment: Try changing `export const regencies` -> `exports.regencies` and `export const provinces` -> `exports.provinces`. Then in your `index.js` file use `const { regencies,  provinces} = require('./location');`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , the location.js file has an error you open an array bracket and the closing bracket is missing .

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two errors in the locaton.js file. Close the array brackets for both regencies and provinces.
2. You can import the following like this:-
   import { provinces,regencies } from './location';
3. And in the script tag add, type="module"

example:-

```js
<script type="module"  src="index.js">
```